# Visiting every cell in grid in the minimum time with these rules?

Tags: algorithm, graph, breadth-first-search

A specimen is placed in an **n X m** size grid which is divided into **1 X 1** cells.

It expands according to following rules.

If at time t, the specimen occupies  **(x ,y)**, then at time t+1 it can expand to at most any two cells out of **(x+1,y), (x-1,y), (x,y+1), (x,y-1)**.

For example if at t = 0 sec if the specimen occupies (4, 5), then at time t = 1 sec, the state of the grid can be any of the following

```
1. specimen at (4,5), (5,5) and (3,5).

2. specimen at (4,5), (5,5) and (4,6).

3. specimen at (4,5), (5,5) and (4,4).

4. specimen at (4,5), (3,5) and (4,6).

5. specimen at (4,5), (3,5) and (4,4).

6. specimen at (4,5), (4,6) and (4,4).
```

**Note**- At t= 2 sec, it can expand from all the points that the specimen occupied at t= 1

I plan to do this with a greedy strategy,with Breadth First Search ,trying to mark at least two nodes in each step,after no two nodes can be marked in single step ,I add up the remaining. Will this approach give an optimal result?

If not how can this be solved?

Comment: Consider a 1xN grid with a specimen on one end. Otherwise, seems legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the farthest corner of the field from the specimen.  For example, if the specimen is in the corner `(1,1)` than the farthest corner would be `(n,m)`.

Let's say the distance to this corner is `dX` along the `x` axis and `dY` along the `y` axis. The most important insight is, that no matter which strategy you chose, you would need at least `dX+dY` steps to colonize this farthest corner. This is easy to establish if one sees, that after `t` steps no cell can be colonized by the specimen which is further away than `t` in Manhattan distance.

Now, if I give you a strategy which colonize the whole field in `dX+dY` steps, than this is an optimal strategy, because any strategy would not have colonized the farthest corner after `dX+dY-1` step.

My strategy looks as follows:

1. phase: for `dX` steps grow in both x direction (as long as both direction possible otherwise only in the direction of the farthest corner). After this phase a whole row of the field is colonized (because our chosen is the farthest).
2. phase: for `dY` steps grow in both y direction: after the first step of this phase there are 3 full colonized rows, after the second step - 5, and so on until `dY` the whole field is colonized, due to the fact (the same as above), that the chosen corner is the farthest.

So the minimum time needed is really `dX+dY`.